# How to access a Button with Selenium, when the button seems to be generated from JavaScript

Tags: java, javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I try to run some tests on a webpage. I'm a beginner and until now everything went pretty smooth.

I'm changing some values in a webform and  now want to press the "Save & Exit" button.
[image]

But when I look at the available source with the webdriver (`driver.getPageSource();`) , I don't see a button, only the below JavaScript. I shortened the script to one button - the one button I would like to click.

```
function getToolbarCfg() {
  return [{ btnId: 2, icon:'images/obj16/tsave_.gif', text:'Save & Exit', qtip:'Save Record and Exit', handler:function() { cwc.getCenterWindow().tpzExecute('2',null,'detail'); } }];
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have the WebDriver wait explicitly for an element to appear.

```
    public static IWebElement WaitForElementToAppear(IWebDriver driver, int waitTime, By waitingElement)
    {
        IWebElement wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(waitTime)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists(waitingElement));
        return wait;
    }
```

Read up on [Selenium's WebDriver Wait Documentation](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#explicit-and-implicit-waits) for a good explanation of explicit and implicit waits.

EDIT:

You could alternatively do this:

```
public static IWebElement WaitForElementToAppear(IWebDriver driver, int waitTime, By waitingElement)
    {
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(waitTime));
        var element = wait.Until(d =>
        {
            var elem = driver.FindElement(waitingElement);
            if (elem.Enabled)
                return elem;
            else return null;
        });
        return element;
    }
```

This will ping the element every .5 seconds until whatever waitTime is defined or to be OR until the element is present.

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution:

The button is executing a JavaScript when clicked. One can directly call that JavaScript function with the Selenium WebDriver.

```
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("cwc.getCenterWindow().tpzExecute('3',null,'detail');");
```

Hope this answer helps people having the same troubles.

Comment: and it would be nice, if the person who down-voted my perfectly fine working solution could at least explain the reason, why he decided to do so.

Comment: Apologies had problems trying to post comment last night. The reason I down voted is because executing JavaScript directly is not actually testing the application. You say that you are writing tests but in actual fact you not proving those buttons are working or even there. In short, your test is not doing what a user would. Using JavaScript should be an absolute last resort when trying test a web page. Have you tried waiting for the buttons to appear in the DOM? Do you need to trigger an event such as mouse over?

Comment: well, that is good input. Thank you.
I have put my Thread to sleep for 2 seconds. The buttons are not there after that intervall.
Do you have any suggestions on how I could proceed to simulate a more "user like scenario" with actually pressing the button?

Comment: Can you post a link to a public facing website?

Comment: You can make Selenium wait until a certain button appears on the page, then click that button. A problem is that there is no uniform way to represent buttons in HTML. Another is that `click()` doesn't always work for whatever reason - so executing bits of JavaScript can still be necessary sometimes. Which doesn't reduce the validity of RobbieWareham's remark.

Comment: The website is not public available - I'm sorry. But I appreciate both your inputs. I will do dome research and try wait for the button to appear. I'll let you know about my progress.